# Why does the 'PREdicate' follow?

Tags: terminology, etymology

> [[ Etymonline for 'predicate (n.)]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=predicate&searchmode=none) ... from ***prae-* "forth, before"** (see [pre-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pre-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + dicare "proclaim," from stem of *dicere* "to speak, to say" (see [diction](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=diction&allowed_in_frame=0)). Grammatical sense is from 1630s. ...
>
> [[ODO:]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/predicate) {noun} {Grammar} 1. = The part of a sentence or clause containing a verb and stating something about the subject
>
> [[OED:]](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/149844?rskey=dPJu9P&result=2&isAdvanced=false) 2.a. = {trans. *Logic*.} To state or assert (something) about the subject of a proposition

In logic, English, and French, the subject usually precedes the predicate. Per contra, the prefix ***prae-*** (in 'predicate') suggests that predicates would FRONT a sentence or proposition, **before** anything else. So why use 'predicate'?

I know of  [Latin's flexible word order](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/9063/5306), but even in Latin, [the most common form is ... SOV](http://ancienthistory.about.com/od/latinfaqs/f/070111-What-Is-the-Latin-Word-Order.htm). So does the prefix ***prae-*** jar with the definitions of 'predicate'?  I heed the Etymological Fallacy.

Comment: It looks like your question contains its own answer.

Comment: You ask if there's a mistake in the etymology and it comes from something else? Or if there was a mistake when the word was made up and it should actually be a different word? Or what?

Comment: @jlawler  I suspect `there was a mistake when the word was made up`. I just don't understand whether and how and why **predicate** relates to the definitions.

Comment: There was no mistake; Norma Loquendi is error-free. Eventually. Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: @jlawler I'm naive in linguistics; so it seems wrong to me because the prefix ***prae-*** contradicts the fact that predicates FOLLOW the subject?

Comment: So you're assuming that _prae_- refers to the front of a word, like _prefix_? That's one way, but all words have more than one meaning. _Forth_ means _forward_, at the front of something moving out, but it dosn't have to be a word. The definition you quote gives _forth_ as one sense; to state forth (or _state forthrightly,_ or _set forth_, as we say nowadays) matches the meaning of predication. Plus, of course, now it's used more in logic than in grammar.

Comment: @jawler Yes, to your first question: `So you're assuming... like prefix?` What did you mean by `That's one way`? (If this is the right term) What way exists for my [paratactic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/parataxis) interpretation?

Answer (score 4):

The Latin-derived grammatical term "predicate" originates in logical usage, as set forth by Aristotle in *The Categories*. Recall that propositions have subjects, and things predicated of them. The Greek term that underlies "predicate" in logic is [κατηγορία](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=%CE%BA%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%B7%CE%B3%CE%BF%CF%81%CE%AF%CE%B1%CE%B9#Perseus:text:1999.04.0057:entry=kathgori/a-contents) (hence "category"), which earlier meant "accusation" (in public), combining "down" and "agora". Latin *[praedico](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=praedicare&la=la&can=praedicare0&prior=proscribere&d=Perseus:text:1999.04.0063:entry=auctio-cn&i=1#lexicon)* similarly means "to declare in public". The common semantics behind the terms is "setting forth". You can't require compositionality of separable prefix + verb combinations in Indo-European.

Comment: +! for using _set forth_, a synonymous calque of _predicate_.